# Sinatra app using omniauth gets Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking in ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, sinatra, omniauth, rack

I have a Sinatra app, that uses omniauth which constantantly gets this error

```
attack prevented by Rack::Protection::SessionHijacking
```

when I try and log in (using a google account).

It works fine in other versions of IE, and on chrome/firefox/safari.

My setup is

```
rack (1.4.1)
rack-force_domain (0.2.0)
rack-protection (1.2.0)

sinatra (1.3.2)
  rack (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.6)
  rack-protection (~> 1.2)
  tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)
omniauth (1.0.3)
  hashie (~> 1.2)
  rack

omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.1.9)
  omniauth (~> 1.0)
  omniauth-oauth2
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)
  oauth2 (~> 0.5.0)
  omniauth (~> 1.0)
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: This might be related to https://github.com/rkh/rack-protection/issues/11 - if you have the time, could you please jump in on that discussion? I am unfortunately unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Good idea - https://github.com/rkh/rack-protection/issues/11#issuecomment-5066417

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This module tracks properties like USER_AGENT and similar (you can check them here: https://github.com/rkh/rack-protection/blob/master/lib/rack/protection/session_hijacking.rb). This error you get, is probably due the one of those properties are changed during the session.
Try to test if everything works with just this module disabled:

```
set :protection, except: :session_hijacking
```

Comment: Ah, disabling session_hijacking does prevent the error. I'm not sure I should keep it disabled for production though. Do you know why it only occurs in IE9?

Comment: This is a good question. Maybe in IE9 one of those headers are changed in some way during the way, but this would need some research. And as for this module, its protection is not really that strong (all those checked headers can be **easily** spoofed), and *can* be problematic. There are other precautions you could take, encrypting session key via SSL most notably, and others, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

Comment: Great, thanks! Disabling session_hijacking will work for now. I've posted the server dumps on http://gist.github.com/2358527, if anyone is curious how the session environments change. I'll dive through them if I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to upgrade your rack-protection gem to v1.5.2 or 1.5.3 (latest).

They removed tracking of HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING from session_hijacking library.